# Use transitor as a switch to ground audio input

Tags: transistors, switches

I have got a probably very dumb question. I was not able to find an answer on the other topics because they always described the use of transistor as a switch for other applications.

I have a circuit with audio signal passing through and going to a speaker. I would like this signal to be grounded unless a 5V TTL signal is on. In this case this will have to go to the speaker. Can I do it with a transistor?

All the example that I found are about something (like a LED) already connected to a a voltage and then with the transistor either grounding its cathode or not and I do not know whether this would work in the other direction (what I would like to do).

Can I use a transitor to ground/mute the audio signal when TTL signal is zero?

Comment: Speaker signal is usually AC and must not have any significant DC offset. Sounds to me like a job for a relay.

Comment: what kind of powers are we talking here? You usually wouldn't *want* to ground your speaker-driving output, because that means converting all amplifier output power to heat in your transistor.

Comment: ie. are you *positively sure* you want to *ground* your output and not just disconnect it? What's the bigger thing you want to build here?

Comment: What you want is an audio Mute control input. But what Amplifier?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the OP is asking about using a transistor to ground the audio input (in the title at least .... the rest of it is unclear)

Comment: No, he says "...in which case it has to go to the speaker", so it's audio *output*. And everything in me says that this is an [XY Problem] (http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Indeed I may not need to grund the audio signal but just disconnect it from the speaker, @MarcusMüller you are right. And yes this should be the job for a relay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is the ability to switch between audio and silence, you can use an analog mux to switch between your audio *input* and ground, instead of the amplifier *output*. As an example, you would ground S1, S2, and A1, hook up your low power audio source to A0, connect A to your amplifier, and use S0 as your switch input.

If you want stereo, you'll need to use a chip that has two analog multiplexers, and repeat for each line.

[image]

Comment: yes this could work but I do not have access to the low power audio source but just the signal getting from the amplifier

Answer (score 2):

> I have a circuit with audio signal passing through and going to a
>   speaker. I would like this signal to be grounded unless a 5V TTL
>   signal is on. In this case this will have to go to the speaker. Can I
>   do it with a transistor?

The easiest cheapest option is to use a 5 volt electromagnetic relay. It has a switch contact operated magnetically by a coil driven electrically. Like one of these: -

[image]
[image]

Pins 2 and 5 are the coil and pins 1, 3 and 4 is a changeover contact.

You might need to consider using a transistor to buffer the coil from the TTL signal because the coil current can be as high as 100 mA. Use this: -

[image]

Take care not to ground the amplifier output in case it gets damaged. Instead open circuit the speaker.

Comment: great thanks! I think this is exactly what I need. And I will not ground the audio signal with the relay but just disconnect it from the speaker. Could you please tell me which kind of transistor I should use?

Comment: [Take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) @MNP_88

Comment: you actually ought to ground the input to the amp when you want no signal, otherwise you are might get low level signals or other odd noises.